# Deducing linear independence from row operations

Tags: matrices

If I have a set of vectors and I use the transpose of these vectors as rows of a matrix, in the reduced row echelon form, does a leading one in every column imply linear independence or is it a leading one in every row? 
Thank you!

Comment: The non-zero rows of the echelon form are independent. If you kept track of row-swapping, the corresponding set of original vectors are independent.

Comment: Thanks! I got confused because I normally use the vectors as the columns.